# Can regular expressions be used in Splunk generating commands?

Tags: splunk

I created a regular expression that filters results based on a field "id" value:

`index=some_index | regex id="222[1-3]{2}00"`

Unfortunally, this search is executed very long because it first generates huge data volume and then filters it.
Can you tell me whether it is possible to use a regular expression inside generating command to decrease execution time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of the generating commands support regular expressions.  Go to ideas.splunk.com to make a case for it.

In the meantime, use a pattern to filter in the search command then refine the results with a regex.

```
index=some_index id="222*" | regex id="222[1-3]{2}00"
```